# Browser overlay obscuring bottom of page

Tags: android, html, css, browser, flexbox

I am attempting a layout consisting of header, content and footer. The header and footer should always be shown and the content should expand to fill any space remaining. I have implemented this in this jsfiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/SuperMe79/204wd5sv/42/

```
.app {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

.header {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.content {
    flex-grow: 1;

    /* this adds a scrollbar when the content takes up more space than available to display */
    overflow: auto;

    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

In the jsfiddle you can see a browser overlay obscures the footer at the bottom. I have a similar problem on my phone where the browser navigation controls obscure the footer.

[image: top]

I can scroll down further but that is a bad user experience.

[image: bottom]

I want the header, footer to always be visible. I can set the height to less than 100vh but this isn't ideally as it's a fudge and the footer is not longer at the bottom of the view on a browser without an overlay such as on my desktop.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

This is a similar issue to these questions but I've used a different approach to positioning and they haven't been answered.

1. [Android browser bottom control bar overlays content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357033/android-browser-bottom-control-bar-overlays-content)
2. [Chrome `position:fixed; bottom: 0;` obscured by Android UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55003456/chrome-positionfixed-bottom-0-obscured-by-android-ui)

Comment: Can you see if this works? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser

Comment: Thanks Dhruvil21_04. The link does describe the problem and suggests a solution that works; changing height from 100vh to -webkit-fill-available. I haven’t gone for this option because Dave Ceddia’s solution seems like it would be more universally supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `height: 100%` instead of `height: 100vh`. You'll probably also need to assign 100% height to every container:

```css
/* full height for every wrapping element and the app itself */
body,
html,
#app,
.app
{
  height: 100%;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

I've got both `#app` and `.app` there because your JSFiddle example has both.

Comment: Thanks Dave. This worked for me on Android and on my desktop. Curiously it didn’t work in jsfiddle; I suspect due to nesting but I’m not going to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Add followings top of the style.css

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Sample is in this link https://codepen.io/LakshithaMadushan/pen/BaoxvNv

Comment: Thank you for attempting to solve my problem. Unfortunately the addition you suggested doesn’t make any difference. The problem isn’t observable in Codepen as there is no browser overlay. You can see it in jsfiddle or when using Chrome on Android. Unfortunately the later is what a large proportion of users of my app will be using.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better, pretty recent solution to this now: using `height: 100dvh` instead of `100vh`.

The Dynamic Viewport Height addresses the described issue on mobile browsers where a displayed address bar messes with the viewport height.